# Why was my self-answer accepted, and why did I get +5 rep?

Tags: support, reputation

I just found that [my own answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241777/which-groups-can-be-lattice-gauge-groups/248772#248772) to [my own question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241777/which-groups-can-be-lattice-gauge-groups) has been marked as accepted today, and I got +5 rep for it.  I didn't do this, and I didn't think it was possible to get rep for accepting your own answer anyhow.  Did some moderator do this, or is this a bug?

Comment: Just to clarify, moderators do not have any special privileges when it comes to accepting answers. We can't accept (or unaccept) an answer on someone else's question. The _only_ way for an answer to get accepted, period, is if the poster of the question clicks that green checkmark. (Well, unless someone at SE is changing the underlying database directly.)

Answer (score 6):

You didn't get +5 for the accept - that was just an unrelated upvote today. The answer was accepted by you yourself back on Apr 10 '16 four minutes after you wrote it, as can be seen from [the timeline](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/248772/timeline).